# How can I get a list of my TFS BackLog Items in a Hierarchical format?

Tags: c#, .net, tfs, tfs-workitem

I am trying to list out all my backlog items, but some backlog items have children backlog items. I would like to list them out this way: BackLogItemParent/BackLogItemChild1/BackLogItemChild2 etc for however many children each parent item has.

I can get all the backlog items:

```
public WorkItemCollection BackLogItems()
        {
            WorkItemCollection results = this.tfsWorkItemStore.Query(
                "Select [System.Id], [System.Title] " +
                "From WorkItems " +
                "Where [Work Item Type] = 'Product BackLog Item' " +
                "And [System.Title] <> '<unused>' " +
                "Order By [System.Title] Asc"
                );

            return results;
        }
```

and potentially doing something like:

```
 private WorkItem GetChildBackLogItems(WorkItem wi)
        {                
            foreach (WorkItemLink wil in wi.WorkItemLinks) 
            {                    
             //some sort of recursive call to get all links if backlog is a parent
             //but may need to filter out by top parent items first.
            }
            return wi;
        }
```

But am having trouble creating a list in the way I would like as I have not quite got a good grasp on how the linking is denoted in the code. I am suspecting that I may need to use the workitemlinks table instead.

In the team explorer there is a "Tree of Work Items" query type that lists these items in a hierarchical fashion, I guess I am trying to do something similar just a bit more flat.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for sharing how you got all the PBI Items, that was very useful for me, may I ask, what is this part of the query for? "And [System.Title] <> '<unused>" Many thanks

Comment: @Alex we have place holder backlog items, to easily copy from, and they are titled '<unused>'

Comment: ah I see, that makes sense, thanks for the reply

Answer (score 1):

If you create a Query in Visual Studio that has what you want you can use "Save as..." To save it to the desktop. This would be a "Hierarchy" query.

You can then get the entire list of workitens as a flat list by passing the query to WorkItemStore.Query().

After that you can iterate and build your tree in code.

Answer (score 0):

I based my code on [Colin's solution](http://www.colinsalmcorner.com/post/using-the-tfs-api-to-display-results-of-a-hierarchical-work-item-query). At the core you need to call [Query.RunLinkQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.workitemtracking.client.query.runlinkquery.aspx) and then [WorkItemStore.GetWorkItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb140391.aspx) to pull down your work items.

Comment: I tried using Colin's solution, but the LINQ breaks when I feed it my workiteminfo list, after refactoring it some, it still does not work. The number of iterations are too great. :(

Comment: Doesn't sound right, could be that you are not following just the Parent-Child links.

I do not understand why you need a hierarchical query, if you want ALL work items: a flat one is enough.